# Basic html table centering in the left td

Tags: html, html-table, center, tablerow

I have a table which I'm going to try to represent this way:

```
-------------------------
| L1 |       R1         | 
------------------------  
| L2 |       R2         |
-------------------------
```

My code is as follows:

```
<div data-role="content" id="div1" align="top" style="padding:3 !important;" >  
        <table border="0" align="CENTER" cellspacing="0" width="100%" style="vertical-    align: text-bottom;" >
        <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td>
            <div id="question1" class="question">
                <input type="text" id="question" />
            <Style>
                #question{
                  font:5px;
                  font-family:verdana;
                }
            </style>        
            </div>
        </td></tr><tr>
        <td width="50"><img id="img2" width="40" height="36" style="float:right; margin-top: 0px;" ></td>
        <td style="text-align:center;">
            <div class="ui-grid-b" >
                <div class="ui-block-a"><button id="button1" type="submit" data-theme="b" style="font-size:0.8em;"></button></div>
                <div class="ui-block-b"><button id="button2" type="submit" data-theme="b" style="font-size:0.8em;"></button></div>   
                <div class="ui-block-c"><button id="button3" type="submit" data-theme="b" style="font-size:0.8em;"></button></div>  
            </div>
        </td>
        </tr>
        </table>
</div>
```

So basically what I'm trying to do is, there is no section L1 in my table. R1 has data and so has R2. There is an image in L2. What I'm trying to do is remove the division between L1 and L2 and the image in L2 should be centered on the table and not just in the TD for L2. How do I do that?

Also the other question I have is, in the following line of code:

```
<input type="text" id="question" />
```

when the value is populated and when I view this in a mobile, the text sometimes goes to the next line. I thought textarea was the only HTML tag which has multiline. Not sure why the text here is going multi-line and how do I avoid it?

Comment: I would need more info on the input multiline issue, which mobile browser? Have a you got a live example? You are correct when you say an input doesn't support multiline.

Comment: I am using the default browser that comes with Safari. I don't have an example right now but with the code snippet that i'm using here, when I populate a value from my jQuery code, I see the text going into 2 lines.

Comment: I changed the <input type="text> to <p>, still no luck. This is a weird problem.

Comment: I'm going to need to see the CSS, HTML and some jQuery, can you get a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) happening which reproduces the problem? The fact that it only happens 'sometimes' isn't helping either. The 'default browser that comes with Safari' doesn't mean anything as Safari is a browser, I take it that you are trying this on an iPhone then?

Comment: I'll try to put it together on jsFiddle. Actually it's happening all the time when the text is longer than the width of the screen, so I was wrong in saying that it is only happening sometimes. I'm not sure if I can put a jsFiddle together but all i'm doing from my jQuery code is $('question').text = "This is a long text etc .............." And yes, I meant I tried it on the default browser on the iPhone which is probably not Safari :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See this bit just under `<table border="0"....`

```
<tr><td></td>
```

Change that to

```
 <tr>
   <td width="50" rowspan="2">
     <img id="img2" width="40" height="36" style="float:right; margin-top: 0px;">
   </td>
```

And then get rid of the `<td></td>` that originally held that image.